# Where is the Masked payload in the data frame

Tags: websocket

We know that in websockets data frame is as follows:
Fin - RSV - OPOCDE - MASK KEY-PAYLOAD LENGTH-(EXTESION IF THERE IS)-MASK
now in the case of receiving a message, which is surely masked, where do I find the masked message exactly is it in the payload?
If so which is normally true, how do I read the part of the masked payload exactly?

Comment: Are you working on a WebSockets parser? If you are, look at the MSB (8th bit) of the length indicator byte. If not, then the masked data would be unmasked by the the time your application receives the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're writing a WebSocket parser, you would will need to check the MSB (most significant bit) of the length indicator (byte index 1 in a zero index buffer).

This is indicated [in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2) at bit number 8 (assuming network byte order).

I wrote [a C WebSockets parser for the facil.io framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/bccb2115f45288311b70ef7440261964ef02d10f/lib/facil/http/parsers/websocket_parser.h). Looking at the way length and masking are handles might help. It pretty much amounts to:

```
uint8_t has_mask = (((uint8_t *)bytes)[1] >> 7) & 1;
```

You might notice [the masking indicator is collected from the 8th bit (MSB) of the second byte in the buffer](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/bccb2115f45288311b70ef7440261964ef02d10f/lib/facil/http/parsers/websocket_parser.h#L392-L393).

The mask itself is always the first 4 bytes in the payload (though, technically, they're not part of the payload). i.e.:

```
uint8_t mask_len = has_mask * 4; // == has_mask << 2
```

The next step would be to XOR the rest of the payload with the mask, if it's there.

Good luck!